# Define generalized parameters for batch file

Tags: batch-file

We have a requirement, where we define a set of generalized parameters and use it various batch files. For the case of Unix we used to define in one script and include this scripts in other scripts where we wanted to use the parameters. Do we have such functionality in batch?

Answer (score 1):

You could build a settings.bat

```
set global1=On
set global2=C:\temp
```

And to *include* it use in any of your scripts `call settings.bat`

Comment: will the functionality change if i call the settings.bat after SETLOCAL?

Comment: @SumitSahu: Depending on what you mean by "change". The variables will still be set by the `settings.bat`. The SETLOCAL will cause their values to be local.